# Sum.ifs for few single cells in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to make sum.ifs formula to sum values in one row based on criteria.

[image: Table1]

In Criteria for Z I want to sum ALL Zs in table and same for D criteria.
Can I use sort of `sum.ifs(A1:C1:E1;B1:D1:F1;G1)` function? Unfortunately `A1:C1:E1` trys to take range, not single cells and I get error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this: (ugly but working)

```
=SUM(IF(A3:E3="Z",OFFSET(A3:E3,0,1),0))
```

It just goes over all cells (even the ones with the values are checked if they equal "Z", but as this is not the case (as they are values), they are skipped).

**Edit (better formulated than the first one):**

Next proposal:

```
=SUM(IF($A3:$E3=F$2,OFFSET($A3:$E3,0,1),0))
```

The dollarsigns are meant for fixing rows and/or columns:

```
$A3:$E3 : we will always be working with columns A to E, but the rows may change.
F$2     : the criteria are always on row 2, but some are in column F ("Z") 
          and some in column G ("D").
```

Comment: It's missing the sum if A3:E3="D"

Comment: @P.b: sorry. I had understood that `"Z"` was a fixed value. I've updated my answer accordingly, now it should work.

Comment: I understood all needed to be summed, but reading it again I think it's ment to sum per letter

Comment: @P.b, "Z" and "D" was fixed values, indeed. Code you provided works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 you could use: `=SUM(FILTER(B3:F3,COUNTIF(G2:H2,A3:E3)>0))`

Not sure if you wanted all summed at once or per letter. To have sum per letter use:
`=SUM(FILTER(B3:F3,COUNTIF(G2:H2,A3:E3)>0))` and drag to the right

Answer (score 0):

Place this in `G3`

```
=SUMIF(A3:E3,{"=Z","=D"},B3:F3)
```

The range `A3:E3` is checked for the criteria of `"=Z"` and `"=D"` in turn, and the range over `B3:F3` is then summed.

[image: zd sums]

Comment: Nice. If you wrap that in SUM you get the total. `=SUM(SUMIF(A3:E3,{"=Z","=D"},B3:F3))`